# How to pass spring model attributes as parameters in Thymeleaf fragments

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a simple CRUD thymeleaf based html page, where I have a list of workers and worker details. Now I want to create, edit or delete a worker. For this actions I use a twitter bootstrap modal dialog.

This works fine, but I have a lot of duplication there, so I want to create a th:fragment which contains the form fields which are the same in details view, create view and edit view. Just the spring model attribute is different.

```
<div th:fragment="workerForm(formId, formAction, worker)">
  <form th:id="${formId}" th:action="${formAction}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputGivenName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Givenname</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="inputGivenName" type="text" class="form-control" th:field="${worker.givenName}"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="inputName" type="text" class="form-control" th:field="${worker.name}"/>        
      </div>
    </div>        
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">        
        <div class="checkbox">        
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" th:field="${worker.active}"/> Active
          </label>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>                          
  </form>
</div>
```

Now I want to include this fragment in the modal dialog ...

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div th:include="workerFragments :: workerForm(newWorkerForm, @{/worker/new}, ${newWorker})"></div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to pass in the model attribute **newWorker** as a paramter into the fragment and thymeleaf will use this instead of the **${worker}**?

NewWorker is set in the spring action as:

```
....
model.addAttribute("newWorker", new WorkerDTO());
....
```

It is not possible with the above code. Here thymeleaf wants to resolve **worker** instead of the passed in **newWorker**. Should the parameter be in another format, or is it not possible for thymeleaf fragments to resolve this?

Answer (score 10):

I resolved a similar issue by passing the name of the field into the fragment instead of passing the attribute itself. So from your include, you would write something like:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div th:include="workerFragments :: workerForm(newWorkerForm, @{/worker/new}, 'newWorker')"></div>
</div>
```

And then with your fragment, you would have the same "worker" fragment variable, but you would have to use the preprocessor to evaluate the variable in the fragment and then you can use the form-backing syntax to use th:field. Your references in your fragment change from ${worker} to *{__${worker}__}

```
<div th:fragment="workerForm(formId, formAction, worker)">
  <form th:id="${formId}" th:action="${formAction}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputGivenName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Givenname</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="inputGivenName" type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{__${worker}__.givenName}"/>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input id="inputName" type="text" class="form-control" th:field="*{__${worker}__.name}"/>        
      </div>
    </div>        
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">        
        <div class="checkbox">        
          <label>
          <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{__${worker}__.active}"/> Active
          </label>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>                          
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: A bit of a Path to the Dark Side, but if you really need `th:field` with `th:include`, there seem to be no other way.

Answer (score 8):

There is a `with` attribute where you can pass in parameters into your view so you're not dependent on the parent. For example,

If you are calling `workerForm` and you wanted to pass in a parameter called `newWorker` with the value of `newWorkerValue`, then you would do the following:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div th:include="workerFragments :: workerForm" th:with="newWorker=${newWorkerValue}"></div>
</div>
```

So within your workerForm template, you can reference `newWorker`. For additional information, check out [8.2 Parameterizable fragment signatures](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#parameterizable-fragment-signatures)

Comment: My problem is that when I try to use the parameter **worker** like in **<input ... th:field="${worker.name}"/>** thymeleaf wants to resolve it to a spring bean and can't find it. But it should not resolve worker instead it should use the provided parameter like **${newWorker}**

Comment: If you want to pass in the value, you need to use `th:value="${newWorker.name}"` `th:field` is used when you're binding a form backed bean.

Comment: Yes I want to bind to a form backed bean. But I want to decide with a parameter which bean should be used. So in my above example **worker** is just a placeholder for the actual bean which is **newWorker**. So for example giving the parameter **newWorker** to the fragment instead of **<input ... th:field="${worker.name}"/>** thymeleaf should use **<input ... th:field="${newWorker.name}"/>**. I assume this is not possible with thymeleaf.